# Recode multiple unique values in tibble column to a single new value using Tidyverse functions

Tags: r

I am trying to learn the tidyverse way of doing things and I was wondering if there was a way using tidyverse functions to recode multiple values in a vector to a single value without all the redundancy. For example, using the following tibble as a very general example, is there a way to eliminate the repeated use of = 'lower', and = 'upper'?. I would think there would be an obvious solution, but I can't find one.

```
library(tidyverse)

T <- tibble(C1 = c('a','A','b','c','B','g','r'))

T

T %>%
  mutate(case = recode(C1, 'a' = 'lower', 'A' = 'upper', 'b' = 'lower', 'c' 
       = 'lower', 'B' = 'upper', 'g' = 'lower', 'r' = 'lower'))
```

base R solution:

```
DF <- data.frame(C1 = c('a','A','b','c','B','g','r'), stringsAsFactors = 
          FALSE)

DF$case <- character(length = nrow(DF))

DF[DF$C1 %in% c('a','b','c','g','r'), ]$case <- 'lower'

DF[DF$C1 %in% c('A','B'), ]$case <- 'upper'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a logical index with `str_detect` and then change it to category needed

```
library(tidyverse)
T %>%
   mutate(case = c('upper', 'lower')[str_detect(C1, '^[a-z]+$')+ 1])
```

---

If it is only single letters, then use `%in%` on built-in alphabet vectors `letters` or `LETTERS`

```
T %>%
   mutate(case = ifelse(C1 %in% letters, 'lower', 'upper'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am looking for a very general solution. I chose this example for simplicity but any vector of character strings could apply, For example: C1  = c('Mazda 3', 'Mazda 6', 'Mazda Miata', 'Honda CRV', 'Honda Accord'), and I wanted to create a new tibble column of car manufacturers C2 = c('Mazda', 'Mazda', 'Mazda', 'Honda',  'Honda').

Comment: @Mike The first option is indeed general. if you change `^[a-z]+$`